# RequireJS, Angular 2 and custom jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, angular, requirejs, angular-cli, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm writing an angular 2 (v2.1.1) web-app that will make use of a plugin called [ng2-datetime](https://github.com/nkalinov/ng2-datetime) (v1.2.1). I also need to integrate a 3th party requirejs (v2.1.15) web-app. I have generated my angular2 app via angular-cli (is using webpack for module binding).

ng2-datetime has the following dependencies:

- Bootstrap3 (CSS only)
- jQuery 2+ (supports v3)
- [Bootstrap-datepicker
  (JS+CSS)](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)

When I integrate the bootstrap-datepicker.js (in the angular-cli.json) AND use requirejs (index.html as script tag) I get the following error: `Mismatched anonymous define() module...`

I have never done something with requirejs and I saw something in the [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch), but I have no idea how to fix it. I don't want requirejs to use the bootstrap-datepicker.js, how can I fix this.

Note with a clean angular2 project, generated via angular-cli, requirejs and jquery just works with no problems. But as soon as I import the script for bootstrap-datepicker it blows up. jQuery runs fine to, stand-alone.

angular-cli.json

```
{
"project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
    "name": "ng2-qlik"
},
"apps": [
    {
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "assets": [
            "assets",
            "favicon.ico"
        ],
        "index": "index.html",
        "main": "main.ts",
        "test": "test.ts",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
        "prefix": "app",
        "mobile": false,
        "styles": [
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            "../node_modules/ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css",
            "styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
            "../node_modules/ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"
        ],
        "environments": {
            "source": "environments/environment.ts",
            "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
    }
],
"addons": [],
"packages": [],
"e2e": {
    "protractor": {
        "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
},
"test": {
    "karma": {
        "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
},
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
        "style": false,
        "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
        "class": false,
        "component": true,
        "directive": true,
        "module": false,
        "pipe": true,
        "service": true
    }
}
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ng2Qlik</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://playground.qlik.com/resources/autogenerated/qlik-styles.css">
    <script src="https://playground.qlik.com/resources/assets/external/requirejs/require.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import * as moment from "moment/moment";
declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
    selection$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, "selectionEvent");
    dateTest1: Date;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.selection$.subscribe((event:MouseEvent) => console.log("Observer", event.detail));

        this.dateTest1 = moment().toDate();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        let text = jQuery(".dateTest1").text();

        jQuery(".dateTest2").text(text);
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<span class="dateTest1">{{dateTest1}}</span>
<span class="dateTest2"></span>
<br />

<datetime [(ngModel)]="dateTest1" [timepicker]="false"></datetime>
```